# how can i create new variable which will add the values of columns conditional on other set of variables ? (Example provided)

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, variables, dplyr

I have four variable for individual members age Of household, age_01,age_02,age_03 and age_04 and four variable for their working hour, work_hr_01, work_hr_02, work_hr_03 and work_hr_04. i want to create  new variable for total working hour for members age 16 and 17 of the households. i have following data:

```
id   age_01 age_02 age_03 age_04 work_hr_01 work_hr_02 work_hr_03 work_hr_04  
 1     24      16      22     16      33         45         55        40
 2     33      17      18     17      40         33         35        39         
 3     33      17      16     16      40         33         34        42
```

desired outcome with two new variable, work_hr_by_16 and work_hr_by_17

```
ID age_01 age_02 age_03 age_04 work_hr_01 work_hr_02 work_hr_03 work_hr_04  work_hr_by_16   work_hr_by_17
1    24      16      22     16      33         45         55        40              85            na
2    33      17      18     17      40         33         35        39              na            72
3    33      17      16     16      40         33         34        42              76            33
```

Comment: Please post the data in a reproducible form. Run `dput(yourdata)` and paste the result of that into the original question. Also, your example is adding `work_hr_01` and `work_hr_04` to get 73 for the first row of the expected answer. Shouldn't this be the sum of `work_hr_02` and `work_hr_04` to make 85?

Comment: yes it should be 85, thanks. i edited. as i'm new  i'm not entirely sure how to make reproducible form. it's a huge data-set i made an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much easier to manage data if you get it in long format with different columns for age and work hour. We can then `filter` and select only those rows where `age` is 16 or 17, `sum` their `work_hr` and get data back in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id, 
               names_to = c('.value', 'num'), 
               names_pattern = '(.*)_(.*)') %>%
  filter(age %in% 16:17) %>%
  group_by(id, age) %>%
  summarise(work_hr = sum(work_hr)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = age, values_from = work_hr, 
              names_prefix = 'work_hr_by_') %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'id')

#    id  work_hr_by_16 work_hr_by_17 age_01 age_02 age_03 age_04 ... 
#  <int>         <int>         <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int> ...
#1     1            85            NA     24     16     22     16 ...
#2     2            NA            72     33     17     18     17 ...
#3     3            76            33     33     17     16     16 ...
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, age_01 = c(24L, 33L, 33L), age_02 = c(16L, 
17L, 17L), age_03 = c(22L, 18L, 16L), age_04 = c(16L, 17L, 16L
), work_hr_01 = c(33L, 40L, 40L), work_hr_02 = c(45L, 33L, 33L
), work_hr_03 = c(55L, 35L, 34L), work_hr_04 = c(40L, 39L, 42L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```